# FadeIn Text Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein

What is the syntax to have the word, "Loading..." fade in before the JSON data gets displayed? Right now, the data is hidden, and nothing is displayed.

```
a1.start = function(hookElementSelection, dataurlForJsonFile) {

    jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'loading',
    text: 'Loading...'
    }).appendTo(hookElementSelection);

    hookElementSelection.hide();
    $("hookElementSelection.loading").fadeIn("fast");

    //resetting data in case this isnt the first run through 
    a1.products = {};
    a1.recipes = {};
    a1.suppliers = {};
    a1.bakedRecipes = [];

    //make an ajax call and wait for success
    $.ajax({url:dataurlForJsonFile}).success(function(data) {

        //get the recipe data
        parseJSONData(data);

        //put the recipes on the page
        $.each(a1.recipes, function(i, recipe) {
            recipe.render(hookElementSelection);
        });
        renderCalculator(hookElementSelection); //add in the final calculation logic
    });
};
```

Comment: Sounds like you want the "Loading..." text to fade in, have a delay, then be replaced by the JSON data. Is that correct? Add a .delay() function to the JSON call.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing hookElementSelection.hide(); $("hookElementSelection.loading").fadeIn("fast");  to

hookElementSelection.children().not("#loading").hide();
hookElementSelection.find("#loading").fadeIn("fast");

Thanks

Comment: Is the loading div geting added?and what about other data?

Comment: Yes, the loading div was added.  The JSON data was displaying before, but it's hidden now.  I want to fade it in.

Comment: Sorry change to hookElementSelection.find("#loading").fadeIn("fast"); sorry I missed that loading was id not class,edited my answer too

Comment: Hi, Please change to hookElementSelection.children().not("#loading").hide();
hookElementSelection.find("#loading").fadeIn("fast");Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tdf48m2t/ . Also edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since hookElementSelection was hidden, changing the element to which it was appended worked.

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'loading',
    text: 'Loading...'
    }).appendTo($("body"));

    $("#loading").fadeIn("slow");
```